# How to run a JavaScript File with the Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a JavaScript file with the Browser since hours.

It's easier for you to understand me with this example, I got the following code for example: (jQuery)

```
var page = 1;

var data = [];
data.push($('#information').text());
page++;
location = 'www.example.com&page='+page;
```

I want to get the text out of the information element of:

```
www.example.com&page=1
www.example.com&page=2
www.example.com&page=3
```

..and so on

Is it possible with a chrome extension? Tried it with PHP, but the site is blocking my attempt from outside.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want to use AJAX, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but are you just trying to run JavaScript in the browser console? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: What/where is "the site"?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

- If you want to run the same snippet, with easy access try using a bookmarklet. [Here is a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj64zJagEJk)
- You want to run JavaScript commands on a page, and interpret the results, use Google Chrome's Developer Tools which you can open with F12 button.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused after reading your question because the question is bit unclear. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var page = 1;
var data = [];
data.push($('#information').text());
page++;
var address = 'www.example.com&page='+page;
window.location.assign(address);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you want. But be careful if the website doesn't support CORS it will not work

```
var page = 1, data = [];
getData();

function getData(){
    if(page>=0){
        $.get('http://websiteurl?page='+page,function(d){
            d = $('<div/>').append(d);
            data.push(d.find('#information').text());
            page++;
            getData();
        }).fail(function(){
            page = -1;
        });
    }
}
```